# can not using sprite on unity 3.5.7

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

sorry for my bad english. i am using unity 3.5.7 version. 
But now i make a game which is based on a game that i got from AssetStore on unity 4.3.4. There is a variable that using Sprite class, but i can't use it on Unity 3.5.7. what can i do to make it work on unity 3.5.7?

and also there is "EaseType" on these code.
but i can't use it too on unity 3.5.7. what code that can change "EaseType" on unity 3.5.7?
please help me. thank you.

well these are the codes

```
public Sprite[] sprites;
string[] sounds = new String[]{"perc","fx","glass","coo","water","cash"};
public EaseType easeType = EaseType.EaseOutBounce;
```

Comment: and what's the error?

Comment: Welcome to SO dwinaandrea!
Stating that something "doesn't work" is not specific enough, few people will be able to help you.  As Thomas Lindvall already asked, please paste the error(s) you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sprite` type is one of a Unity 2D features, which were introduced in Unity 4.3 release (see [changelog](http://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-4.3)).

So, there is no way you could use it. Also using packages prepared for newer versions usually won't work in older releases. So you cannot do anything about that, you need to upgrade to 4.3 version if you want to use unity 2D toolset.

Comment: Thank you kreys. but i have to do it with unity 3.5.7 because we want to develop game on old mobile version.

Comment: Then you're going to have to write your own Sprite code. Depending on the required functionality, that's not necessarily a huge issue.

Comment: You can use newest Unity to develop for older devices too, nothing has changed. Just make efficient coding and not expensive rendering, and you will be fine.